# Typescript compiling options to support vendor libraries

Tags: model-view-controller, typescript, esri

Issue:  In a freshly generated MVC 5 web project I have the option to set Typescript's compile option to none, RequireJS, or CommonJS.  This is a site-wide compile option.

In a particular view, I need to work with esri's javascript api.  This api encapsulates both RequireJS and Dojo, and if I choose RequireJS as the typescript compile option, everything works fine.

If I want to use typescript anywhere else in the site I have one of two problems: either the JavaScript emitted is in RequireJS format (no RequireJS is loaded outside of the one view) or if I load RequireJS into the project, I get conflicts with the esri library.

For more background see my [Blog Post](http://forrealcoding.blogspot.com/)

Question:  Is it possible to specify individual page(s) compile using different options for JavaScript emission within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to break your solution into multiple projects. In one project you can configure typescript to use AMD modules.

A second option would be to turn off the compiling of typescript at build time by Visual Studio and set up a gulp or grunt task to compile your typescript. This way you can choose to compile one set of files with AMD modules and another without AMD and not have to break your solution into multiple projects.